# Error in 3D rendering with xtk on Remote Desktop

Tags: xtk

We are trying to implement WebGL for a 3D user interface. We have some users that need access through a Remote Desktop connection, however, WebGL is disabled. When loading a page with WebGL on a Remote Desktop, the error "Oops... Sorry, experimental-webgl context is not supported on this machine!... " appears and the 3D rendering fails. The 2D rendering works. We were wondering if there is a way around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL doesn't work with remote desktop because remote desktop opens up another desktop and isn't attached to the hardware display, thus I would assume WebGL has the same limitations. You will need to do a different type of remote desktop maybe vnc or even join.me seems to work fine.